# How to count number of points inside a circle

Tags: python

[I got this plot and I want to divide this plot into many different circles and need how many points in each circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOr8d.png)

I am trying to plot radius of the circle with how many number of points inside the circle.

Comment: Hint: A point is inside a circle if the distance from the point to the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle.

Comment: Do you mean you actually have a PNG image with axes drawn on it? Or you have a Numpy array from which you made the plot?

Comment: Please do the [tour] and ensure your question follows the guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

**Intuition:-** Finding the distance between two points. (i.e sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)) **[Euclidean Formula]**

> 1. If Distance>Radius than point is **outside the circle**
> 2. If Distance=Radius than point is **on the circle**
> 3. If Distance<Radius than point is **inside the circle**

**Code:-**

```
import math
# Lets say the circle points are x=2 y=3
x,y=2,3
# Radius of a Circle radius=4
radius=4
# Given points to check -:
lis=[(-1,1),(4,3),(5,4),(9,10),(1,2),(2,7)]
res=[]
for x1,y1 in lis:  # x1,y1 points to check is it inside or not
    if math.sqrt((x1-x)**2+(y1-y)**2)<radius:  #Note use "<=radius" if you want point which is on the circle also
        res.append((x1,y1))
print(res)  #The points which are inside in the circle
```

**Output:-**

```
[(-1, 1), (4, 3), (5, 4), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Or omit the `math.sqrt()` and check if less than `r*r`.

Comment: yes that will be the nice option. instead of using `if math.sqrt((x1-x)**2+(y1-y)**2)<radius:` we can use `if (x1-x)**2+(y1-y)**2<radius*radius:`